# Array out of bounds exception when reading file from the command line. Java

Tags: java, exception

So, I'm trying to read a file like by line in java and compare it to all the words in another file and see how many of them match.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int wordFound = 0;
    String wordCheck;
    File file = new File("wordlist.txt");
    File input = new File(args[0]);
    Boolean searchResult;
```

Either way this is my main, and im just trying to set args[0] as filename.

I am running my program like so:
    ? java SpellChecker >input.txt

So i guess it could be args[2] but i tried that and I'm still getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException whenever i use any number in there O.o

I would appreciate any help.

THANKS!

Comment: Try removing the `>` from the command line args.

Answer (score 1):

Your way, `java SpellChecker > input.txt` means all outputs of your programs will be written in `input.txt`. That means if you do any kind of print, it will be written in `input.txt`.

The command you need is `java SpellChecker input.txt`